# Create testprogram for java

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to create a test program for my program.

I have written this so far:

```
class Flygplan{

    private int altitude;
    private int course;
    private int speed;
    private String model;

    public Flygplan (int altitude, int course, int speed, String model){
        this.altitude = altitude; 
        this.course = course;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.model = model;
    }
    public void setAltitude(int newAltitude){
        this.altitude = newAltitude;
    }
    public int getAltitude(){
        return altitude;
    }
    public void setCourse(int newCourse){
        this.course = newCourse;
    }
    public int getCourse(){
        return course;
    }
    public void setSpeed(int newSpeed){
        this.speed = newSpeed;
    }
    public int getSpeed(){
        return speed;
    }
    public void setModel(String newModel){
        this.model = newModel;
    }
    public String getModel(){
        return model;
    }
    public void Print(){                         
        System.out.println("Höjd: " + altitude + "\nRiktning: " + course + "\nHastighet: " + speed + "\nModell: " + model + "\n ");
    }
}
```

and

```
class TestFlygplan{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Flygplan flyg1 = new Flygplan (100, 1, 200, "Cargo");       
        flyg1.setAltitude(1100);
        int newAltitude = flyg1.getAltitude();
        assert newAltitude == 1100: "Felaktig altitud. Borde varit 1100 men var " + newAltitude;

        flyg1.setCourse(2);
        int newCourse = flyg1.getCourse();
        assert newCourse == 2: "Felaktig riktning. Borde varit 2 men var " + newCourse;

        flyg1.setSpeed(1000);
        int newSpeed = flyg1.getSpeed();
        assert newSpeed == 1000: "Felaktig hastighet. Borde varit 1000 men var " + newSpeed;

        flyg1.setModel("Fighter");
        String newModel = flyg1.getModel();
        assert newModel == "Modell": "Felaktig modell. Borde varit Fighter men var " + newModel;

        Flygplan flyg2 = new Flygplan (1000, 3, 300, "Charter");

        flyg2.setAltitude(12000);
        int newAltitude2 = flyg2.getAltitude();
        assert newAltitude2 == 12000: "Felaktig altitud. Borde varit 12000 men var " + newAltitude2;

        flyg2.setCourse(1);
        int newCourse2 = flyg2.getCourse();
        assert newCourse2 == 1: "Felaktig riktning. Borde varit 1 men var " + newCourse2;

        flyg2.setSpeed(9000);
        int newSpeed2 = flyg2.getSpeed();
        assert newSpeed2 == 9000: "Felaktig hastighet. Borde varit 9000 men var " + newSpeed;

        flyg2.setModel("Boeing");
        String newModel2 = flyg2.getModel();
        assert newModel2 == "Modell": "Felaktig modell. Borde varit Boeing men var " + newModel;

        flyg1.Print();
        flyg2.Print();      
    }
}
```

As you see I've tried to use assert, but  I havent been able to activate it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html

You must use something like `assertEquals(a, b);`

Comment: Thanx for your help. I finally found how to activate asserts.

Answer (score 0):

In order to "activate" asserts you have to pass the flag `-ea` (enable asserts).

The following is a screenshot of IntelliJ "Run Configuration" screen that shows where to configure it

[image]

See [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#enable-disable) for additional details